# (Done) Re-Open: Being told you're not liked and should quit

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120043/being-told-youre-not-liked-and-asked-to-quit-at-work)

Was closed using the "company specific/legal advice" reason, personally I think this was incorrect. From the meta post addressing that close reason:

> Questions should be able to be answered by an HR professional in another company

Any UK HR professional who doesn't know whether the described situation qualifies as harassment under the Equality Act (and in fact it's general applicability) has done a serious amount of lying to get into (and keep) their job so this doesn't count as seeking legal advice just because he mentioned the name of a piece of legislation.

Nor does this only really address a specific company since the situation could easily occur in any company in any field.

Answer (score 2):

I edited the title for extra clarity and reopened.  (There were three other votes already.)